# websocket error "cannot read property '0.562521108193323' of undefined" when trying to update pack on client nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I am creating a game with websockets and node.js but am having some difficulty, once logged in I get the error: `cannot read property '0.562521108193323'` of undefined in regards to the code `var p = Player.Li[pack.id];`

Sorry I am fairly new to all of this.

The error occurs within (line 183 on js fiddle - index.html). So it is something to do with updating the pack based on the information received from the client?
Lots of code so - JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wwyhrtdw/#&togetherjs=KF83cDq9VR

If anybody could help me that would be great.

Comment: Anyone able to help?

Comment: This error message means that: 1. `pack.id` is `0.562521108193323` (String or Number). 2. `Player.Li` is _undefined_. And also means you can infer `Player` _is_ defined.

Comment: A quick glance through your code shows code using a `Player_Li` - this is different to `Player.Li` - do you have a typo?

Comment: Player_LI is a list of all players in the game. Where Player.Li is used I am accessing the id's within the list. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes 0.562521108193323 is the id of the player trying to connect to the game when I log in.

Comment: I am also getting the error `cannot convert undefined or null to object` on line 215 of index.html

Answer (score 0):

I think I have rectified the issue by changing all that variables to Attack_Li & Player_Li. However I am now getting `ctx.fillrect is not a function`